# How to clone a constructor function so that it constructs a copy of the original type that behaves just like the original, but has its own prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototype-programming

I am trying to clone a constructor function completely, so that it does exactly the same as the original but its prototype is set to a clone of the original.

I can easily clone the original prototype like so:

```
  // the original constructor function is assigned to the `type` variable.

    const prototype = type.prototype;
    const clonePrototype = Object.create(null);
    const props = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(prototype);
    for (let i = 0; i < props.length; ++i) {
        const propertyName = props[i];

        const propDescriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(prototype, propertyName);

        Object.defineProperty(clonePrototype, propertyName,
              Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(prototype, propertyName));
    }
```

The issue I'm having is how to create a constructor function now that has its `prototype` property set to the `clonePrototype` object.

If I do:

```
    const newContructor = function() {};
    Object.setPrototypeOf(newContructor, clonePrototype);
```

then newConstructor ends up with `__proto__` set to the `clonePrototype` object, and the `prototype` property unchanged. I'd like to leave `__proto__` unchanged, and `prototype` set to the new value.

My goal is to clone this constructor function so that it constructs a copy of the original type that behaves just like the original, but has its own prototype.

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: function expressions don't create constructors.

Comment: @RandyCasburn OK, and how to accomplish it then?

Comment: Well, start with a function declaration. Since a constructor, by definition in the spec creates a plain object, then your entire idea is blown out. You can achieve your goal though. A constructor can return any Object as the "constructed" context. So, build up your object including adding the prototype inside the constructor. Then Simply return the Object you defined. Done.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I think I got it. But how can I pass in that prototype object I want to set without changing the constructor signature? Would you mind posting an example of what you suggested as an answer? This way I can mark it as resolved as well. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to naively show you two solutions:

1. Answers your "how to" question directly (per comments)
2. The JavaScript way of producing the result

I say naively, because perhaps there is some use case that requires the cloning to occur (perhaps some time after the `Type` prototype has changed over time). But, given your code examples, the JavaScript way presumes unmodified prototypes.

So here is the first. Note the changes I made was to convert the function expression:

`const newContructor = function() {};`

To a function declaration:

`function NewConstructor() {};`

And since you `Object.create`'d the clone, I `Object.assign`'d it to the prototype.

```js
function Type() {};
Type.prototype = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: function() {
    console.log(this.a + " + " + this.b + " = " + (this.a + this.b));
  }
}

const prototype = Type.prototype;
const clonePrototype = Object.create(null);
const props = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(prototype);
for (let i = 0; i < props.length; ++i) {
  const propertyName = props[i];
  const propDescriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(prototype, propertyName);
  Object.defineProperty(clonePrototype, propertyName,
    Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(prototype, propertyName));
}

function NewConstructor() {};
Object.assign(NewConstructor.prototype, clonePrototype);
/********************************************/
let type = new Type();
const cloned = new NewConstructor();

type.c(); // prints 1 + 2 = 3
cloned.c(); // prints 1 + 2 = 3

Object.getPrototypeOf(type).a = 0;
// Alternative syntax that some will dislike and point out it should not be used 
cloned.__proto__.a = 3;

type.c(); // prints 0 + 2 = 2
cloned.c(); // prints 3 + 2 = 5
// Here are the independent prototypes (or type.__proto__ and cloned.__proto__
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(type), Object.getPrototypeOf(cloned));
```

If the prototype is a pristine prototype when the cloning occurs, it is much more direct to use the prototype as a constructor itself. This allows you to use the `new` operator with your prototype to construct a **Singleton** instance of the prototype itself.

In this example you will see no cloning of the prototype. A singleton version of the prototype is created for each object that needs it as a prototype.

The mutation of each prototype is then observed as independent from one another:

```js
function MyPrototype() {
  this.a = 1;
  this.b = 2;
  this.c = function() {
    console.log(this.a + " + " + this.b + " = " + (this.a + this.b));
  };
}

function Type() {};

function NewConstructor() {};

Type.prototype = new MyPrototype();
NewConstructor.prototype = new MyPrototype();
/********************************************/
let type = new Type();
const cloned = new NewConstructor();

type.c(); // prints 1 + 2 = 3
cloned.c(); // prints 1 + 2 = 3

Object.getPrototypeOf(type).a = 0;
// Alternative syntax that some will dislike and point out it should not be used 
cloned.__proto__.a = 3;

type.c(); // prints 0 + 2 = 2
cloned.c(); // prints 3 + 2 = 5
// Here are the independent prototypes (or type.__proto__ and cloned.__proto__
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(type), Object.getPrototypeOf(cloned));
```